# Recommendation of device+software to listen to audible.com audiobook

Tags: ipod, mp3-player, audiobooks, audible

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and I am searching for some way to easily, and legally listen to audible.com audiobooks in an external device.

I have an 2008 second generation iPod shuffle (which I gained as a gift, before converting to Linux) and I am having a really bad time in trying to use it in my current system.

I have already tried to use it through iTunes installed in PlayOnLinux, and in a virtual Win7 in VirtualBox (what would be a complete overkill in RAM usage and $$) with no success.

I have also tried installing gtkpod and following [its instructions](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Getting_started#Mounting) but it seemed to me that my system does not meet some [conditions](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Getting_started#Introduction) for it to work.

The only thing I really want is some effective and inexpensive way to directly listen to the .aa files (that are sold in audible.com) in an external device. I really would not have any issues buying another device (and would even prefer to, so get off Apple), provided it could directly play those .aa (or, more generally any DRM) files, or is a there an easy and legal way to convert them into mp3/mp4 files.

Comment: I have e-mailed audible.com and they answered:

_"At this time, we are working with the open-source developers of Linux to see if we can make our file format compatible with their operating system. If that happens, we do expect to expand our support to Linux computers in the future. We would love to make our content available to Linux users as soon as possible, as we often hear from Linux fans regarding Audible playback."_